# Convert CSV data to JSON POJO for large file

Tags: java, csv

I am using CsvMapper to convert a CSV file to a list of POJO JSON objects for potentially large files.

```java
byte [] csvData ...
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper()
       ...
CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper
        .schemaFor(MyPojo.class)
        .withHeader();
MappingIterator<MyPojo> mappedLines = csvMapper.readerFor(MyPojo.class)
        .with(csvSchema)
        .readValues(csvData);

mappedLines.forEachRemaining(myPojo -> doSomeAction(myPojo));
```

This reads all the values to a MappingIterator.

Is it possible to only read one record at a time and then doSomeAction? (to minimize the memory utilisation for very large CSV files)

Comment: You haven’t asked a question.

Comment: What's wrong with using `Iterator.hasNext`/`Iterator.next` inherited by `MappingIterator` **one** time using `if`?

Comment: Which library is this?

Comment: Additionally, if you have read your data to a byte array, it definitely means a possible large memory footprint depending on the data volume. Use I/O streams/iterators everywhere possible,